# Find the number of five-digit multiples of $5$, where all the digits are different, and the second digit (from the left) is odd.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of five-digit multiples of $5$, where all the digits are different, and the second digit (from the left) is odd.

Comment: Any thoughts?  Hint:  saying it is a multiple of $5$ is the same as saying it ends in $0$ or $5$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Well, how many five digit numbers are there.  How many multiples of 5 are there.  How many 5 digit numbers have different digits.  How many digits have an odd digit in the second place.  How would you combine this.  Hint.  Figure out how many ways there are to choose on digit.  Then how many ways to choose another.  Then... think.

Answer (score 2):

Here as the number should be divisible by 5, last digit must be either 0 or 5

So consider two cases...

- case 1:-last digit is 0
  In this case, you will have now 9 digits left (as all the digits are different). Also you can fill second place using one of 5 odd digits out of remaining 9 digits. Now start filling from 1st place, which can be filled in 8, 3rd in 7 and 4th in 6 ways.

So in total you will have (8)(7)(6)(5) = 1680 numbers of case 1.

- case 2:- last digit is 5
   In this case you have now 4 odd digits and 5 even digits including 0. So now you can fill second place with remaining 4 odd digits. Now you are left with 3 odd digits and 5 even digits. So starting from 1st place, you can fill 1st place in 7 ways(you can't fill 1st place with 0), 3rd place with 7 ways(now you can include 0) and 4th place with 6 ways...

So in total in case 2 you have (7)(4)(7)(6) = 1176 numbers.

So, total of case 1 and case 2 will give you 2856 numbers.